# Problemas con lentitud de base de datos al realizar consultas en windows azure

Tags: azure-sql, azure-storage

Estoy actualmente trabajando desde una aplicación realizada en c# con una base de datos en windows azure, la pregunta es que al momento de realizar una búsqueda por ejemplo de un cliente al yo tipear se visualiza como una lentitud al tipear cosa que cuando laboraba con una base de datos local no sucedía, tengo la opción escogida de modelo de compra basado en dtu con la opción básico, si alguien me podría guiar si esta es la opción correcta o debo escoger otro tipo de plan, el software básicamente trabaja con consulta de cliente y registro de informacion de historiales clínico y presupuestos.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    
    namespace DientesSanos.dao
    {
    
        public partial class Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto
        {
            public string PRE_COD { get; set; }
            public string PRE_COD_PAC { get; set; }
            public string PRE_NOM_PAC { get; set; }
            public string PRE_COD_ODON { get; set; }
            public string PRE_NOM_ODON { get; set; }
            public string PRE_RUT { get; set; }
            public string PRE_ELA_PRE { get; set; }
    
    
            public static List<Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto> Busqueda_Paciente_Presupuesto(String Nom_Pac)
            {
                List<Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto> listHc = new List<Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto>();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand sql;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1;
                String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = new SqlCommand("Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto", conn);
                    Console.WriteLine(sql);
                    if (conn != null)
                    {
                        sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        sql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NOMPACHISCLI", Nom_Pac));
                        sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql;
                        sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto dsr = new Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto
                        {
                            PRE_COD = r["PRE_COD"].ToString(),
                            PRE_COD_PAC = r["PRE_COD_PAC"].ToString(),
                            PRE_NOM_PAC = r["PRE_NOM_PAC"].ToString(),
                            PRE_COD_ODON = r["PRE_COD_ODON"].ToString(),
                            PRE_NOM_ODON = r["PRE_NOM_ODON"].ToString(),
                            PRE_RUT = r["PRE_RUT"].ToString(),
                            PRE_ELA_PRE = r["PRE_ELA_PRE"].ToString(),
                        };
                        listHc.Add(dsr);
                    }
                    return listHc;
                }
            }
        }
    }

 private void txtBusqueda_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridPre.DataSource = null;
            List<Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto> Pre_Nom_Fil = new List<Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto>();
            if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                daoOdont.Cargar_Historial_Presupuesto(dataGridPre);
            }
            else if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length < 3)
            {
                Presupuesto_Nombre = null;
                return;
            }
            else if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length == 3 && rdbApe.Checked == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(txtBusqueda.Text.Length);
                Presupuesto_Nombre = Buscar_Paciente_Presupuesto.Busqueda_Paciente_Presupuesto(txtBusqueda.Text);
                Pre_Nom_Fil = Presupuesto_Nombre;
                Console.WriteLine(txtBusqueda.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                Pre_Nom_Fil = Presupuesto_Nombre.FindAll(x => x.PRE_NOM_PAC.Contains(txtBusqueda.Text));
                dataGridPre.DataSource = Pre_Nom_Fil;
            }
        }
```

Después de varios días de ayuda y pruebas adjunto el resultado del mismo esperando que a otras personas les puedo servir y guiar hacia la solución sin mayor problema.